# Retrieve data from multiple tables in hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, multiple-tables

I have 2 tables namely subscriber and contact.
Tables look something like this:

```
subscriber -> id, contact_id //contact_id is a foreign key
contact -> id, firstName, lastName, email, contactType
```

My Contact.hbm.xml file looks like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.DBNAME.model.Contact" table="contact" >

        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>

        <property name="contactType" type="int">
            <column name="contactType" sql-type="TINYINT"></column>
        </property>
        <property name="firstName" type="string">
            <column name="firstName"></column>
        </property>
        <property name="lastName" type="string">
            <column name="lastName"></column>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And my Subscriber.hbm.xml file looks like this :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.DBNAME.model.Subscriber" table="subscriber" >

        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>

        <many-to-one name="contact" class="com.DBNAME.model.Contact" column="contact_id" unique="true" fetch="join"/>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now I want to retrieve a simple Subscriber object in which contact gets mapped automatically. So what I do in Java code is :

```
/**
     * get Subscribers
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void getSubscribersWithContactDetails() {
        Session session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            setSubscribers((List<Subscriber>)session.createQuery("from Subscriber").list());
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        }

/**
     * @param subscribers the subscribers to set
     */
    public void setSubscribers(List<Subscriber> subscribers) {
        this.subscribers = subscribers;
    }
```

My data classes looks like the following :

```
    public class Contact implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private int id;
        private int contactType;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
    // Getters Setters and constructors
    }


public class Subscriber implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int         id;
    private Contact     contact; //Foreign Key from Contact -> id
    private int         contactId;
//Constructors, Getters and Setters
}
```

And my query generated by Hibernate looks like this :

```
select subscriber0_.id as id1_, subscriber0_.contact_id as contact2_1_ from subscriber subscriber0_
```

I am not getting contact details from contacts table. How will I be able to do that?

Comment: contact object is null and all the details inside contact are set to Null.

Comment: use 'lazy=false' in your .hbm file. It is true in your case because of which you are getting null entries.

Once you use this option, it will keep the data in subscriber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
 <many-to-one name="contact" 
     class="com.DBNAME.model.Contact" column="contact_id" 
     unique="true" lazy="false"/>
```

I.e. `lazy="false"` and no `fetch` attribute.

Comment: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of com.smackdab.model.Contact.shipAddressId

Comment: I have this one shipAddressId as well in Contact table. And it empty at the moment. :s

Comment: If you have `Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type` it means that most probably `contactType` or `contactId` column contains null values. Try to change its type to Integer.

Comment: Love you for the quick answer! Brotherly love! :D ... But how did you figure out the lazy=false thing? I didnt get it. And btw for now I changed the fields from int to string so it can accept all the fields as null! ;)

Comment: You can also change it to `Integer`. Just a lot of experience with Hibernate :)

Comment: Practice + Stackoverflow + Internet Search. Just trying different approaches for different projects. After a certain amount you know what works, what is awkward, and what should be avoided.